# Connecting to my personal laptop from corporate laptop while WFH

Tags: windows-10, networking, vpn, remote-desktop

Like most of us, I'm still working from home. My work machine (company laptop) runs Windows 10 and I use a VPN to connect to office servers. My personal laptop also runs Windows 10. I'd like to have connectivity to my personal laptop  via it's PC name (access it via it's computer name) like I do to company servers.

From what I know about VPNs, it creates a separate network and use a tunnel to access my work network. So while I'm connected to the VPN, I see two different private networks. Let's say one of them is a WAN (10.x.x.x) and other a local LAN (192.168.x.x).

I can ping from my work laptop to my personal laptop (via the LAN) although company network policy doesn't allow the reverse. Nonetheless, what I want is to be able to identify my home machine via it's computer name and also have that laptop show up in the discovered devices on my work laptop.

Currently If my home laptop acquires a new IP, then I have to check that and use the IP address via the RDP on my work machine. I'd like to create a network shortcut to my home machine that persists reboots and one that is able to connects to it regardless of whatever IP address it has.

Comment: Why not just set a static IP address for it on your router? [DHCP would normally keep re-assigning the same IP just as 'habit' but it isn't compulsory]

Comment: Give your laptop a static IP on your network and then include that in the HOSTS file of the company machine and include the name of your laptop in the HOSTS file. Then you can make a shortcut on the company machine. Works here.

Comment: What you try to do may well by forbidden by your company's IT policy as it it very similar to connecting unauthorised devices eg USBs to company laptops/networks. I would be fired if I tried that at home.

Comment: As mentioned before, check your company policy, many companies don't allow what you just say. then if it does go for a static IP, will simplify the whole process.
Cheers